# Bootstrap-Select Plugin with Angular JS and ajax data not working

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, bootstrap-select

http://plnkr.co/edit/1ATuPILnevk6gCvYRvee?p=preview

```
angular.module('emfModule')
  .directive('selectpicker', function ($timeout) {
      return {
          restrict: 'C',
          link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

              var $el = $(element);
              $timeout(function () {

                  $el.selectpicker({
                      style: 'btn-default',
                      size: false
                  });


              });


          }
      };
  });
```

Hi I am trying to load data via ajax into a dropdown in an angular app. The data is coming through and  i am able to populate the control but when I try to use the bootstrap-select plugin, it fails. I tried to wrap it up using an angular directive but didnt help. The Plunk above describes my use case. Can someone let me know where I am going wrong. Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://plnkr.co/edit/7YR5R4aTFWDelwFDz7jV?p=preview

I've changed you selectpicker directive. It's waiting until data for options loads + a bit more time for angular so it could rebuild select. And only after that I call select-bootstrap plugin. And also directive restrict changed from C to A.

```
angular.module('emfModule')
.directive('selectpicker', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      var $el = $(element);

      var unsubscribe = scope.$watch(attrs.selectpickerOptions, function(opts) {
        if (opts) {
          $timeout(function() {
            $el.selectpicker({
              style: 'btn-default',
              size: false
            });
            unsubscribe();
          });
        }
      })

    }
  };
});
```

And here's you element. I've removed class selectpicker because I don't want select-bootstrap call himself.

```
<select title="Select" ng-options="c.login  for c in Users" ng-model="login" name="login" selectpicker="" selectpicker-options="Users" class="form-control input-sm">
   <option value="">-- choose user --</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Beautiful. It works. Thanks a lot. However, Would you share some light on the following 2 things: (1). Why are you calling the unsubscribe function again within the timeout?  (2)What did you mean by "I don't want select-bootstrap call himself". Why would it call itself if I had it in the original form as a class instead of an attribute

Comment: Also, once you select an item in the dropdown, any further items that you select is actually selecting the next item in index to the seleted item in the list.

Comment: The issue goes away if we actually set the model to the first element or some other valid element of the drop down, but I do not want to select an item intiallly and have the drop down intialize with "Select" as seein in the Plunkr

Comment: I've made correction to fix this issue. See new plunker. About questions:
1) I call unsubscribe once after make sure that options are loaded cause I want to disable watch and prevent second call of bootstrap-select in future
2) Class selectpicker has special meaning for bootstrap-select plugin. When element with this class detected it became wrapped automatically.